# Clang - C++ 11 standard from 2011, 2014

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm building Cogutils and Opencog on OS X 10.10.5.

-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 6.1.0.6020053
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 6.1.0.6020053

```
/Users/davidlaxer/cogutils/opencog/util/files.cc:55:39: error: non-
aggregate type 'const std::vector<std::string>' cannot be initialized with 
an initializer list static const std::vector<std::string> paths = ^1 error generated.
```

Additionally, there were warnings of the type:

`deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:~ davidlaxer$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix

David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:~ davidlaxer$ port search clang
Bear @2.0.3 (devel)
    Bear is a tool to generate compilation database for clang tooling.

clang-2.9 @2.9_15 (lang)
    this port is only a stub and has been made obsolete by clang-3.4

clang-3.0 @3.0_14 (lang)
    this port is only a stub and has been made obsolete by clang-3.4

clang-3.1 @3.1_9 (lang)
    this port is only a stub and has been made obsolete by clang-3.4

clang-3.2 @3.2_4 (lang)
    this port is only a stub and has been made obsolete by clang-3.4

clang-3.3 @3.3_8 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang-3.4 @3.4.2_9 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang-3.5 @3.5.2_6 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang-3.6 @3.6.1_2 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang-3.7 @3.7-r245076_1 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang-3.8 @3.8-r245076_1 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang_select @1.0 (sysutils)
    common files for selecting default clang version

mpich-clang @3.1.4_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-clang33 @3.1.4_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-clang34 @3.1.4_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-clang35 @3.1.4_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-clang36 @3.1.4_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-clang37 @3.1.4_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-devel-clang @3.2b3_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-devel-clang33 @3.2b3_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-devel-clang34 @3.2b3_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-devel-clang35 @3.2b3_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-devel-clang36 @3.2b3_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

mpich-devel-clang37 @3.2b3_1 (science, parallel, net)
    Message Passing Interface (MPI) Library

openmpi-clang @1.7.5_5 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-clang33 @1.7.5_5 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-clang34 @1.7.5_5 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-clang35 @1.7.5_5 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-clang36 @1.7.5_5 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-clang37 @1.7.5_5 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-devel-clang @1.9a1_34660 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-devel-clang33 @1.9a1_34660 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-devel-clang34 @1.9a1_34660 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-devel-clang35 @1.9a1_34660 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-devel-clang36 @1.9a1_34660 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

openmpi-devel-clang37 @1.9a1_34660 (science, parallel, net)
    A High Performance Message Passing Library

Found 36 ports.
```

Any suggestions on which version of clang/llvm I need or what compiler flags should be invoked?

Comment: You need `-std=c++11`. Your current clang version is fine.

Comment: I'm using cmake.  Just, append -std=c++11 to CMAKE_C_FLAGS and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ?  Or all the MACROS:  CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG, CMAKE_C_FLAGS_PROFILE, CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE, ...